# Formula to convert Gram/Kilo to Gram/Pound

Tags: math, formula, data-conversion

I am looking for the formula to convert Gram/Kilo to Gram/Pound

Example:
1 g/kg = 0.45 g/lb

Here is a calculator to do it on Google:

https://www.google.co.nz/search?safe=off&espv=2&q=gram+per+kilo+to+gram+per+pound

Does anyone know the formula?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly a programming question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You practically have the formula in the question:

g/kg * 0.45 = g/lb.

Comment: Hmmm thanks, sometimes it takes another set of eyes to point out the obvious!